# How to sum up value in session - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to sum up all the values returned from a session but I'm unable to achieve this with `array_sum();` but return nothing. Below is what my code looks like:

```
<?php 
                                        
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['img_src']);$i++){

    $subTotal = $_SESSION['price'][$i];
    echo $subTotal;

   }
                            
?>
```

In the above code `echo $subTotal;` returns `9,999 11,999 9,999` and I tried using `echo array_sum($subTotal);` but got nothing and I want to be able to get a sum up to be `31,997`

Comment: Do your values really have commas in them?  You'll need to remove the commas to have them recognized as numbers.

Comment: I used ```preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $subTotal);``` to remove the comma and the result was ```9999 11999 9999```and still ```array_sum()``` still didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the exact code you now have.  You can't remove the commas from the `$subTotal` string, you have to remove them from the `$_SESSION['price']` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all of the commas in one call:

```
<?php
$values = array("9,999","11,999","9,999");
$sum = array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $values ));
echo "$sum\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>php x.php
31997
```

Replace `$values` with `$_SESSION['price']` in your case, of course, so your code ends up as this, and NOTHING more:

```
<?php
$sum = array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $_SESSION['price']));
echo "$sum\n";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but it returns no value and I tried a test with your code and it didn't sum up.

Comment: I'm showing you the literal cut-and-pasted outcome from my computer.  That code produced the result you see.  All you need to do is make the change I mentioned at the last line.  It does work.

Comment: I added it like this and it returned no result: ```for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['img_src']);$i++){$subTotal = $_SESSION['price'][$i];
$sum = array_sum( str_replace(",", "", $subTotal ));
echo "$sum\n";}```

Comment: Nope, that's not right.  You are not following my example.  **You do not need a loop.** Just use the two lines of code I have above.